# Will i be charged for overriding empty onchildadded() of firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to firebase and trying to understand how firebase billing works.In my app i do get all my data and processing it in onChildchanged() (one data at a time). i dont need to override onChildadded() but childeventlistener forced me to override it ( onchildadded() gets all data everytime my app opens so i leave it as empty).My question is - will i get charged for overriding empty onchildadded(). for example if i write a code like this. will i be charged for implementing this.

```
  reference2.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {


            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {
                        User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                        Log.d("users", "onchildchanged" + user.getprofile());
                        }
               
            }
            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For the purpose of billing, it doesn't matter at all what you do in your listener code.  Once you attach that listener, the query will happen, and billing will occur regardless of what your listener does with any snapshots that get delivered to it.

Comment: Then how can I get data that only I want.sometimes I get only one item and other times I get two or four item.is there any other way to stop onchildadded to retrieve all data when I open my app.

Comment: You should only attach a listener to the data you want to read.  It sounds like you might want to review how value event listeners work in Realtime Database.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events

Comment: I don't understand.can you please elaborate.i couldn't remove onchildadded from that listener.for ex- my app is a chat app I can send and receive all my messages through onchildchanged one at a time.are you saying I will get charged for onchildadded datasnapshot too.

Comment: No, my answer is saying that it doesn't matter at all what code is in your listener.  Just leave the callback empty if you don't want to use it.  It doesn't cost anything.  It sounds like you might just be confused about how queries work.  If a query isn't working the way you expect, please post a new question that shows the database data, the code that makes the query, and what isn't working the way you expect.

Comment: Thank you for that link.i didn't read that page before.it looks like query can only limit the data we receiving.my query points to all messages in chat node that contains more than 1000 message s and I tried to send & receive one message at a time in onchildchanged.

Comment: There is a difference in billing for ValueEventListener vs ChildEventListener at the same path though right? I presume for ChildEventListener you only get billed for the children added, removed, changed, moved?